# How to programmatically access words from the built-in Windows Phone 7 dictionary?

Tags: windows-phone-7, spell-checking

I am writing a windows phone application on SDK 7.1. I have a requirement where in I want to check whether a particular keyword is a valid English word. Windows Phone has build-in spelling checker. How can I get access to it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is currently a way to access this inbuilt functionality. I would recommend you go down the route of reading in an xml dictionary, a quick google search should give you one as they are commonly used.